# Undetected_chromedriver log info not printing on console

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I am using undetected_chromedriver bt its not printing log info like (Dev tool listening to...).
I've used it previously and the same code was printing log info. Here is my code

```
def get_chromedriver():
    import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
    browser = uc.Chrome(headless=True, executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
    browser.maximize_window()
    return browser

driver = get_chromedriver()
```

Comment: What is the use case  even if it's not printing ?

Comment: I am running it in headless mode and the script pause at certain point forever. I want to see the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, here is an example to get the Devtools log information print in the console. This is take straight from the documentation . You need to add the `driver.add_cdp_listener()` method with the appropriate params to print the logs from `DevTools`

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from pprint import pformat
driver = uc.Chrome(enable_cdp_events=True)
driver.maximize_window()

def printmessage(message):
    print(pformat(message))

driver.add_cdp_listener("Network.requestWillBeSent",printmessage)

# to print all evenets
driver.add_cdp_listener('*', printmessage)


with driver:
    driver.get('https://workchronicles.com/comics/')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The this produces detailed output but not what I require. I just need the link that come after message (Dev tool listening to...). I just need general log info that usually get printed but for me its not printing that log info.